# How to take out a list from another list with a dictionary in it using Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Current dictionary is [[{ data }]]

```
[[{'stat': 'Ok', 'time': '22-12-2022 15:25:00', 'ssboe': '1671702900', 'into': '332.40', 'inth': '332.80', 'intl': '332.00', 'intc': '332.45', 'intvwap': '332.30', 'intv': '140828', 'intoi': '0', 'v': '6583955', 'oi': '0'}, {'stat': 'Ok', 'time': '22-12-2022 15:20:00', 'ssboe': '1671702600', 'into': '332.30', 'inth': '332.45', 'intl': '332.25', 'intc': '332.35', 'intvwap': '332.23', 'intv': '117775', 'intoi': '0', 'v': '6443127', 'oi': '0'}]]
```

Expected dictionary is [{ data }]

```
[{'stat': 'Ok', 'time': '22-12-2022 15:25:00', 'ssboe': '1671702900', 'into': '332.40', 'inth': '332.80', 'intl': '332.00', 'intc': '332.45', 'intvwap': '332.30', 'intv': '140828', 'intoi': '0', 'v': '6583955', 'oi': '0'}, {'stat': 'Ok', 'time': '22-12-2022 15:20:00', 'ssboe': '1671702600', 'into': '332.30', 'inth': '332.45', 'intl': '332.25', 'intc': '332.35', 'intvwap': '332.23', 'intv': '117775', 'intoi': '0', 'v': '6443127', 'oi': '0'}]
```

Comment: Just `list[0]`? The fact that there is a dict inside the inner list is not important in any way. Even that what you want to get is a list. Your question is basically *"how to get the first element of a list"* which is covered in any basic tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Just get the first index like so:

```
new_list_of_data = old_list_of_data[0]
```